# How to use ruby hash shorthand syntax with SpaceAfterComma rule of rubocop?

Tags: rubocop

So i have these two configurations in my rubocop.yml file

```
Layout/SpaceAfterColon:
  Enabled: true

Style/HashSyntax:
  EnforcedShorthandSyntax: always
```

This shows missing space after colon when i try to use short hand syntax for hash or function call codeclimate shows missing space after colon issue.

If space is given, shows white space before comma issue or trailing white space issue depending on the context.

I would like to use short hand syntax, without seeing missing space after colon issue but have space after colon when not using short hand. white space before comma and trailing white space should also be enabled.

None of the combination of styles works.

Answer (score 0):

apart from above settings

in project `.rubocop.yaml`

`AllCops:`

`TargetRubyVersion: 3.1`